# Unsure which tests to use now that my continuous symptom scale has been replaced with its underlying subscales

Tags: regression, spss, large-data, interaction

I've been working with a large data set in SPSS, mostly focused on the symptom scales of one developmental disorder. I have data from two separate time points, a few years apart. So for example I've checked the stability of this developmental disorder across the two time points using a linear regression (as they are continuous variables). I have also looked at its relationship from the earlier age, with another disorder diagnosis at the later age. Here I used a logistic regression as the later variable was categorical. I've then rerun each test  using PROCESS to include a moderator.

However, I've come to the conclusion that it would make more sense to look at all my aims again, but instead using the two underlying subscales for the developmental disorder.

So I guess for the stability test, it would be 2 continuous IVs/2 continuous DVs. And for the logistic regression, two continuous IVs and one categorical DV.

Yet I'm totally baffled as to how to which tests to use now that I'm including the two continuous subscales instead of the overall sum of symptoms... I know these may seem really stupid but I'd appreciate any help, as I'm going round in circles and all the papers I've read online seem to be irrelevant or on a whole new level of stats to me.